# Fatal error while compiling Nexus6p (aarch64) kernel on MacOS

Tags: android, build, kernel

I have compiled a Nexus5 kernel in arm32 and everything went well on MacOS. But errors occurred while compiling Nexus6p kernel in aarch64. Anyone who knows what happened ?

```
warning: (PCI_MSM && AMD_IOMMU) selects PCI_MSI which has unmet direct dependencies (PCI && ARCH_SUPPORTS_MSI)
warning: (SND_SOC_APQ8074 && SND_SOC_MSM8994) selects SND_SOC_MSM_HDMI_CODEC_RX which has unmet direct dependencies (SOUND && !M68K && !UML && SND && SND_SOC && FB_MSM_MDSS_HDMI_PANEL && (SND_SOC_MSM8974 || SND_SOC_APQ8084 || SND_SOC_MSM8994))
warning: (ARCH_MSM) selects DEVFREQ_GOV_MSM_BW_HWMON which has unmet direct dependencies (PM_DEVFREQ && (ARCH_MSM_KRAIT || ARCH_MSM_BIMC_BWMON))
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
  GEN     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o
scripts/mod/file2alias.c:85:10: warning: '__used' macro redefined
      [-Wmacro-redefined]
# define __used                 __attribute__((__used__))
         ^
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:166:9: note: previous definition is here
#define __used          __attribute__((used))
        ^
1 warning generated.
  HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _devtable_ptr374 from scripts/mod/file2alias.o. To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
  HOSTCC  scripts/sortextable
In file included from scripts/sortextable.c:31:
/Volumes/Transcend/Android_Kernel/msm_angler/tools/include/tools/be_byteshift.h:4:10: fatal error:
      'linux/types.h' file not found
#include <linux/types.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [scripts/sortextable] Error 1
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
```

The toolchain I use was generated by make-standalone-toolchain.sh:

```
./make-standalone-toolchain.sh --arch=arm64 --platform=android-24 --install-dir=/Users/Don/my-android-toolchain64 --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9
```